# Intepreting Pandas Column Referencing Syntax

Tags: python, pandas

I have a basic background in using R for data wrangling but am new to Python. I came across this code snippet from a tutorial on Coursera.

Can someone please explain to me what  **columns ={col:'Gold' + col[4:]}, inplace = True**  means?

(1) From my understanding, df.rename is to rename the existing column name to (in the case of first line, Gold) but why is there a need to +col[4:] after it?

(2) Does declaring the function **inplace as True** mean to assign the resulting df output to the original df?

```html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', index_col=0, skiprows=1)

for col in df.columns:
    if col[:2]=='01':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='02':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='03':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:1]=='№':
        df.rename(columns={col:'#'+col[1:]}, inplace=True)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like 'Gold'+col[4:] is what the new name will be. Specifying the original column names will help answer your question.

Comment: @rohit-biswas the original column name is **01 !** before it's replaced with "Gold"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means:

```
#for each column name
for col in df.columns:
    #check first 2 chars for 01
    if col[:2]=='01':
        #replace column name with text gold and all characters after 4th letter
        df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    #similar like above
    if col[:2]=='02':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    #similar like above
    if col[:2]=='03':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    #check first letter
    if col[:1]=='№':
        #add # after first letter
        df.rename(columns={col:'#'+col[1:]}, inplace=True)
```

> Does declaring the function inplace as True mean to assign the resulting df output to the original dataframe

Yes, you are right. It replace inplace columns names.

Comment: @Rosellx - So now understand? Or necessary something explain more?

Comment: yes, understood the purpose of **inplace** now, but what is the implication if I don't declare inplace when renaming a dataframe's column?

Comment: @Rosellx - then use `df = df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]})` - simply assign values back

Comment: which means **df = df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]})** will just be a temporary renaming on the column? In other words, **inplace=False** will keep the original column name of the dataframe, right?

Comment: @Rosellx - It is alternative for code with no `inplace`

Answer (score 0):

```py
if col[:2]=='01':
        #replace column name with text gold and all characters after 4th letter
        df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
```

(1). If col has a column name of '01xx1234',
1. col[:2] = 01 is True
2. 'Gold'+col[4:] => 'Gold'+col[4:] => 'Gold1234'
3. so, '01xx1234' is replaced by 'Gold1234'.

(2) `inplace = True` applies directly to a dataframe and does not return a result.
If you do not add this option, you have to do like this.
`df = df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]})`

Answer (score 0):

**inplace=True means**: The columns will be renamed in your original dataframe (df)

Your case (inplace=True):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns={"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"}, inplace=True)

print(df.columns)
# Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')
# df already has the renamed columns, because inplace=True.
```

If you wouldn't use inplace=True, then the rename method would generate a new dataframe, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
new_frame = df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})

print(df.columns) 
# Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object') 
# It contains the old column names

print(new_frame.columns)
# Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object') 
# It's a new dataframe and has renamed columns
```

NOTE: In this case, better approach to assign the new dataframe to the original dataframe (df)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
df = df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})
```